# Why javascript promises shows <anonymous> location in error logs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, es6-promise

I want to log the fileName, lineNo, ColNo in my codeBase. For that i am using _thisLine().
It basically fetches the line no. by creating(not throwing) an error.
But this approach fails if i call thisLine() from promise

Can you please help me!

```
    function _thisLine() {
  const e = new Error();
  const regex = /\((.*):(\d+):(\d+)\)$/;
  const match = regex.exec(e.stack.split("\n")[2]); //i dont want to change thisLine function
  return match
    ? {
        filepath: match[1],
        line: match[2],
        column: match[3]
      }
    : "NOT FOUND";
}
function without() {
  return _thisLine(); // this is ok
}
function withPromise() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var result = _thisLine(); //inside promise unable to capture current line number
    resolve(result);
  });
}
console.log("without Promise", without());
withPromise().then(function(result) {
  console.log("with    Promise", result);
});
```

i expect the withPromise to return the trigger point location
but due to promise .. i am unable to find trigger point

[image]

### ANSWER (my workaround)!works for me!

```
  private _thisLine() {
    const e = new Error();
    // for path like - 'LogWrapper.debug (D:\\Projects\\rrr\\node\\build\\server\\log_server\\log_wrapper.js:101:14)'
    const regex1 = /\((.*):(\d+):(\d+)\)$/;
    // for path like - 'D:\\Projects\\rrr\\node\\build\\server\\http_repo\\labtest_repo.js:58:24'
    const regex2 = /(.*):(\d+):(\d+)$/;

    let match = null,
      callStackDepth = 2,
      errorExploded = e.stack.split("\n");

    while (!!!match) {
      //match both kind of path patterns
      match =
        regex1.exec(errorExploded[callStackDepth]) ||
        regex2.exec(errorExploded[callStackDepth]);

      //if not found then move to nearest path
      callStackDepth--;
    }

    return {
      filepath: match[1],
      line: match[2],
      column: match[3]
    };
  }
```

Comment: `anonymous` refers to the function passed into the `Promise`, i.e. it's an unnamed (anonymous) function

Comment: It could still (technically) include the location though, no?

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks .. that made me think.. I have updated the answer

Comment: @user2864740 In fact it does, in the trace line above `at new Promise`: it's line 19 column 17 of your file, isn't it? I would consider that formatting of one stack frame into two lines to be a bug of your environment however. Please report it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Withdrawn - pending unacceptance***

*Promise settlement handlers being executed with a clean stack was incorrectly interpreted as explaining why an* Error *object created inside such a handler would be missing call stack trace data.*

*The data isn't missing.*

*Logging the error in a browser. and drilling down in the console, shows the presence of entries in the* `new Error().stack` *property array.*

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation. Can you please suggest a promise lib that does that?

Comment: Please unaccept this answer - it was based on an assumption that `_thisLine` worked  correctly and _therefore_  no trace information was available in the Error object. Both turning out to be wrong :-(  You could accept @Karthikeyan 's answer if it solved the problem or post your own. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to fix your regex. (I am not an epxert in regex)I am guessing your regex is expecting the location data to be enclosed inside parentheses "()"  and when its triggered inside promise since there is no parantheses returned by  `e.stack.split("\n")[2]` , executing regex on that is returning null.

I have added some console.log to print out the values

```js
function _thisLine() {
       const e = new Error();
       const regex = /\((.*):(\d+):(\d+)\)$/;
       const match = regex.exec(e.stack.split("\n")[2]);
       console.log('trigger location...'+e.stack.split("\n")[2]);
       console.log('match...'+match);
       return match
         ? {
             filepath: match[1],
             line: match[2],
             column: match[3]
           }
           : "NOT FOUND";
}
function without() {
  return _thisLine(); // this is ok
}
function withPromise() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var result = _thisLine(); //inside promise unable to capture current line number
 console.log('result is ...' + result);
    resolve(result);
  });
}
console.log("without Promise", without());
withPromise().then(function(result) {
  console.log("with    Promise", result);
});
```